# In which situations will FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId() fail?

Tags: java, android

I am developing an Android application for api 23 to 28.

In code I have something like this when the user logs in:

`FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<..>{ //and here i am logging in in oncomplete() })`

In which situations will this code fail?

I have tested it so far in emulators where they do not have play services installed and it's working well... so I want to take in consideration the case when this will fail because if it fails on one device, the user will not be able to log in and he will give my app a low rating.

Please note that What I'm trying to do is to send the firebase token to the server so that i can send notifications to specific users meeting some criteria.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, you wouldn't see any failures when calling the lines of code you have outlined.  But you would likely want to check if the task was successful within `onComplete`.

Just because the task has completed and `onComplete` has been called does not mean that you have successfully retrieved a token.  Within `onComplete` you can call `task.isSuccessful()` to determine if a token is available.  [Take a look at their example code snippet here.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#retrieve-the-current-registration-token) I am guessing that the devices without Google Play Services are calling `onComplete` but the task is not successful and there is no token available.  If this is the case, you might want to prevent them from logging in because there is no token - and only log them in if the task is successful and you got a token.

For example, I have tested similar code on an Amazon Fire Tablet (with no Google Play Services) and `onComplete` is triggered but `task.isSuccessful()` returns `false` and `task.getException()` gives me `MISSING_INSTANCEID_SERVICE` which indicates that the device does not have Google Play Services and therefore cannot retrieve a token.  You have to be careful for devices that don't have Google Play Services or may have an old, unsupported version of Google Play Services.

With all of that said, I have never encountered a situation in which `onComplete` was not called.  For me, it has always been called almost instantaneously and I have never seen any failures with calling those specific lines.  I just think you need to do some additional work within the `onComplete` to make sure it was successful.